# Replace matches using regex by modifying matched string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, replace

Im trying to replace matched strings using regex in swift, my requirement is as below

`originalString = "It is live now at Germany(DE)"`

i want the string within the `(" ")` i.e`DE` to be separated by space i.e. "D E"

so *replacedString* should be `"It is live now at Germany(D E)"`

i tried below code

```
var value: NSMutableString = "It is live now at Germany(DE)"
let pattern = "(\\([A-Za-z ]+\\))"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
regex?.replaceMatches(in: value, options: .reportProgress, range: 
NSRange(location: 0,length: value.length), withTemplate: " $1 ")
print(value)
```

output is `It is live now at Germany (DE)`, i know it's not what is required.
here it is based on the template where we cannot modify based on matched string value. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the format fixed as `(`+`2 letters`+`)`? Try `value.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]\\))", with: "$1 $2", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)`

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for your response. No it is not fixed with 2 letters it can be more than 2 as well.

Comment: Ok, so that is always `(`, then 1 or more spaces or letters and then a `)`, right?

Comment: Yes, just to give another example "(SOFE)" should be "(S O F E)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
var value: NSMutableString = "It is live now at Germany(DE) or (SOFE)"
let pattern = "(?<=\\G(?<!\\A)|\\()[A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]+\\))"
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
regex?.replaceMatches(in: value, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange(location: 0,length: value.length), withTemplate: "$0 ")
print(value)
```

Or just

```
let val =  "It is live now at Germany(DE) or (SOFE)"
let pattern = "(?<=\\G(?<!\\A)|\\()[A-Za-z](?=[A-Za-z]+\\))"
print( val.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "$0 ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil) )
```

Output: `It is live now at Germany(D E) or (S O F E)`

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=\\G(?<!\\A)|\\()`  - a positive lookbehind that matches a location right after `(` or at the end of the preceding successful match
- `[A-Za-z]` - matches and consumes any ASCII letter
- `(?=[A-Za-z]+\\))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with 1+ ASCII letters and then a `)` char.

The `$0` in the replacement inserts the whole match value back into the resulting string.

Comment: It works. But i have a query, which part of the regex is adding space " " between the characters?. Sorry if it is a silly question as my understanding of RegEx is that of a beginner

Comment: @RajeshRs `withTemplate: "$0 "` / `with: "$0 "` - do you see the space now? Regex never inserts or add anything, regex patterns are used to *search for* strings meeting some pattern. The replacement patterns are used to add/insert chars to/instead of matches.